# Does weak convergence ($X_n\Rightarrow X$) imply weak convergence of the difference to zero ($X_n-X\Rightarrow 0$)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of random variables weakly converging to $X$ ($X_n\Rightarrow X$) as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I am wondering if this implies that $X_n-X\Rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$? I know the converse is true via continuous mapping, but I would like to know if the two statements are actually equivalent? I believe it should be true as we could use the Skorokhod representation theorem to get the almost sure convergence of the difference to $0$, and thus the weak convergence of the difference to $0$, but I am not sure if this is correct? Any ideas or comments would be greatly appreciated.

edit: my reasoning using SRT was as follows: $X_n\Rightarrow X$ so there exist copies $Y_n$ and $Y$ with respective laws equal to those of $X_n$ and $X$ on another probability space (say $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mathbb{Q}))$ such that $Y_n\rightarrow Y$ $\mathbb{Q}$-a.s. As $Y\rightarrow Y$ $\mathbb{Q}$-a.s, then $Y_n-Y\rightarrow 0$ $\mathbb{Q}$-a.s and therefore $Y_n-Y\Rightarrow 0$, and $X_n-Y\Rightarrow 0$. There must be a mistake here somewhere, but I can't seem to see where?

Comment: It is the final "and" that is the problem; $Y_n - Y$ converging in distribution to 0 does not imply anything about $X_n - Y$. (A simple counter-example would be $Y_n = Y$, and $X_n = -Y_n$ where $Y_n$ has a symmetric distribution that is not a.s. 0. (OP I know you are probably way over this, but I am leaving this here in hopes that it will help others)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. Weak convergence does not require the $X_n$ and $X$ to live on the same probability space. Even if they all do, here's a counterexample. Toss a fair coin once and let $X$ be the number of heads seen, let $Y$ be the number of tails seen (so $X+Y=1$), and define $X_n=Y$ for all $n$. Then everybody has the same distribution, so $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$. However, the difference $X_n-X=1-2X$ does not converge weakly to zero; it takes values $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. Do you see why my reasoning above using SRT is incorrect?

Comment: The SRT states that there exist versions of $X_n$ and $X$ defined on a probability space for which there is a.s. convergence of $X_n$ to $X$. However, this probability space need not equal the space where you are currently 'working'. For the above counterexample the SRT would take $\Omega$ to be the unit interval and would define $X_n$ to be identical to $X$, in which case $X_n-X$ indeed converges pointwise to zero and therefore $X_n-X$ converges weakly to zero.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was under the impression that we could "switch back" to the original probability space, as in the proof of the extended continuous mapping theorem, for example on page 105 of http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/framechno.pdf  Do you see what is the difference between my argument and this short proof?

Comment: Note that the conclusion when you "switch back" is that $g(X_n)$ converges in distribution to $g(X)$. It does not assert that $g(X_n)-g(X)$ converges in distribution to $0$. The reason why you cannot deduce this is that if $X_n$ and $X$ are not on the same probability space, then it makes no sense to talk about $X_n-X$.